# Run Atom using a bat file after changing directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, atom-feed

I have writen in my bat file

```
cmd /k cd /d"C:\Users\amanz\Desktop\Introduction - Computing\Java files" 
call atomer.bat
```

right now, it just seems to change the directory and stops right there. It doesn't seem to call the atomer.bat file.

The following code is seen in the atomer.bat file:

```
start atom .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It just seems to change the directory and stops right there

```
cmd /k cd /d"C:\Users\amanz\Desktop\Introduction - Computing\Java files"
```

There are two errors with the above:

1. `cmd /k` runs a command **and then returns to the CMD prompt** (which terminates the batch file and goes back to the `cmd` shell where you called it from).
2. You should have a space after the `/d` before the `[drive:][path]` argument.

In fact, you don't need to use `cmd` at all (it is not needed for what you want to do).

Use the following batch file:

```
cd /d "C:\Users\amanz\Desktop\Introduction - Computing\Java files" 
call atomer.bat
```

This assumes that `atomer.bat` is either:

- located in the directory `C:\Users\amanz\Desktop\Introduction - Computing\Java files`, or
- located somewhere on your path.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [cd](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) - Change Directory - Select a Folder (and drive)
- [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.